# How Can I get or create reference File in firebase-admin Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin, cloud-storage

I'm working with Firebase-admin and I want to know how create or get reference of a File.

With this reference I'm going to save it in the Firestore with the reference data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I would try (Typescript example):

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

admin
  .storage()
  .bucket()
  .file('path/to/myfile.jpg')
  .getMetadata()
  .then(apiResponse => {
    console.log(apiResponse)
  })
```